# How to smart redirect 404 page to search page with keywords from URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have recently gone through a couple of site transfers and permalinks have been changed along with my domain. I have a lot of links both on social media and reddit that have old links. They are being directed to a 404 page. Is there any way to smartly direct these pages to a search page that uses keywords from the url?

Here is my current HTACCESS:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Here is an example of a link that doesn't work:**

https://lifeandhealth.co/2016/06/12/book-club-sapiens-by-yuval-harari/

**Here is the new link:**

https://prestopost.org/book-club-sapiens-by-yuval-harari/

All the articles are on the site, and can be found with a one or two keywords from the end of the url.

Is there a plugin, or preferably some code to add in that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: Put your search URL.

Comment: @SyedNoman ok, for the link that i have provided, this would be an example of a good search: [link] (http://prestopost.org/?s=sapiens+book+club)

Comment: You can't do this in .htaccess with WordPress unless you target a specific/unique URL pattern relating to these old URLs. Because WP itself needs route all non-existent URLs through its own routing mechanism. You would need to do something _after_ WP has finished with it and it then defaults to a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my point of view so here you go.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?s=$1 [NC,L,R=404]
```

**Edit:**

Or you maybe use this plugin [Smarty 404](http://atastypixel.com/blog/wordpress/plugins/smart-404/).

Comment: Thanks Syed, I have tried it, but its not doing anything.

Comment: Do you know of a plugin that does this?

Comment: Wait let me check. so here you go http://atastypixel.com/blog/wordpress/plugins/smart-404/

Comment: You know, i took a look at this earlier and was cautious because it is over 2 year old, so i never bothered. But i have tried it and it works! Thanks Syed.

Comment: You can't do this sort of thing in .htaccess since it will break WordPress (if the directive is in the correct place, above the WP stuff. Or, if its not in the right place, it will do nothing). But also, `R=404` doesn't do what you think it does... it will cause the substitution to be dropped completely and Apache will serve its own 404 page, no redirect will be triggered. This will need to be done _within_ WordPress.